# php move vaiable substring to end of string

Tags: php, string, variables, redirect

say I have a string:

```
something.something/search?&abc=xyz:??????q=hello+there
```

or
`something.something/search?abc=xyz:??????q=hello+there`

I need to move variable substring: `[&]abc=xyz:??????` to the end of sting.
So I wind up with: 
`something.something/search?q=hello+there&abc=xyz:??????`

The substring is unknown at the start in terms of how long it is.

We know the substring starts right after the first `?` and that it
starts with `&abc=xyz:?????` possibly or `abc=xyx:?????` possibly.

There may or may not be the `?????` and they are of indeterminate length.
and content.
We know the the substring ends at the `q=......`.
So what is between first `?` to first `q=` gets removed and added to string.

However that ending must begin with an `&` and only 1 `&`.

All this only applies for strings containing `something.something/search?`.

The substring is quite a variable.

I am also wondering if I should test for something before I try the change.

Thanks

It says to edit question so here goes. I think you are getting close. 
A typical $url would be:
https://www._oogle.com/search?&tbs=qdr:q=hello+there //hello+there only example.
https://www._oogle.com/search?tbs=qdr:q=hello+there  //...qdr:null|h|d|w|m|y which is for past page searches. (how old) null(all),hour,day,week,month,year.
If the tbs:qdr part comes first other things break, so I have to move it after
the q=... part.
And of course the are the http:// varients to be considered.

I was thinking to use a contains function I made to see if this $url needs this treatment. It needs to catch the "_oogle.com/search?&tbs=qdr:" possibility however. (starts with ampersand) [null|&]tbs=qdr:[null|h|d|w|m|y] . I guess there could possibly be other parameters before the "q=" part, but lets worry about that later.

```
if (contains($url, "_oogle.com/search?tbs=qdr:"))

function contains($haystack, $needle) {
if(stristr($haystack, $needle) === FALSE) { return false; }
else {return $needle; }
```

Comment: Thanks Mark, would that be parse_url or parse_str?

Comment: I'll give all these a try and let you know.

Comment: Ok, so I should use a function as an array will be used?

Comment: I'm not clear on if and how I would test to see if this is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is exactly what you are looking for, but your can try to use a regex on your params. If you have more params before and after the `q=` you will have to manipulate the regex a little more and you will have to loop in an array to define the correct position of the param you are looking for. Here is an example of what you could do.

```
$baseUrl = 'http://www.google.com';
$parseUrl = parse_url($baseUrl.'/search?&abc=xyz:??????q=hello+there');
preg_match_all('/&?(.*)q=(.*)/',$parseUrl['query'],$matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
echo $baseUrl.'/search?q='.$matches[2][0].'&'.$matches[1][0];
```

Comment: Yes. You are good. I see where you are going. I will try to put an answer. 1-hello there is different each time.  I think Google, which this is for BTW, usually starts with https:, but sometimes http: comes in. The ???? is just for example. The abc:xyz: is for the age of search hits sought. It can be search?[null|&]tbs=qdr:[null|h|d|w|m|y]  So simplicity lets assume there is nothing between the end the tbs=qdr part and the q= part. Glad you came in. I was going nuts with php function. Lastly, I want to test for if all this would apply to the any given $url?